# Reading in OSM buildings geojson data into Python via geopandas

Tags: python-2.7, openstreetmap, geojson, geopandas, imposm

I'm having problems reading an OpenStreetMap buildings (IMPOSM GEOJSON) file into a geopandas data frame object (Python 2.7). This is on MAC OS X 10.11.3. Here are the messages I'm getting:

```
>>> import geopandas as gpd
>>> df=gpd.read_file('san-francisco-bay_california_buildings.geojson')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Users/ewang/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/geopandas/io/file.py", line 28, in read_file
gdf = GeoDataFrame.from_features(f, crs=crs)
File "/Users/ewang/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/geopandas/geodataframe.py", line 193, in from_features
d = {'geometry': shape(f['geometry']) if f['geometry'] else None}
File "/Users/ewang/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shapely/geometry/geo.py", line 34, in shape
return Polygon(ob["coordinates"][0], ob["coordinates"][1:])
File "/Users/ewang/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shapely/geometry/polygon.py", line 229, in __init__
self._geom, self._ndim = geos_polygon_from_py(shell, holes)
File "/Users/ewang/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shapely/geometry/polygon.py", line 508, in geos_polygon_from_py
geos_shell, ndim = geos_linearring_from_py(shell)
File "/Users/ewang/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shapely/geometry/polygon.py", line 450, in geos_linearring_from_py
n = len(ob[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The odd thing is that I can load OSM roads data IMPOSM GEOJSON files with geopandas. Am I missing something obvious here? Thanks very much.

EDIT - link to the data below:
[OSM data from mapzen](https://s3.amazonaws.com/metro-extracts.mapzen.com/san-francisco-bay_california.imposm-geojson.zip)

Comment: Can you provide a link to the data?

Comment: Hi joris, I updated to include the link.

Comment: the data is not available anymore